# Is there Delphi-like extended RTTI in C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

### Context

(*Actual question below*)

#### Easy in Delphi

I regularly convert API headers to Delphi. Sometimes there are problems with struct alignment, or I miss a packing option like `#pragma pack(push, 1)`. To check if I have the proper alignment and size, I display the offsets in my translated records with this simple function using extended RTTI:

```delphi
procedure WriteOffsets(Info: Pointer);
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LField: TRttiField;
begin
  LType := LContext.GetType(Info);
  if Assigned(LType) then
    if LType.TypeKind = tkRecord then
    begin
      Writeln(('  ' + LType.QualifiedName + ' = record ').PadRight(48),
        ' // size ', LType.TypeSize);
      for LField in LType.GetFields do
        Writeln(('    ' + LField.Name + ': ' + LField.FieldType.Name + ';').PadRight(48),
          ' // offset ', LField.Offset);
      Writeln('  end;');
      Writeln;
    end
    else
    begin
      Writeln(LType.QualifiedName, ' is not a record');
    end
  else
    Writeln('Invalid type');
end;
```

and then call it with:

```delphi
WriteOffsets(TypeInfo(TSecurityDescriptor));
```

That nicely writes the size and offsets for each member field, so I can check this with a similar output generated by C++Builder. The function generates something like this:

```delphi
  Winapi.Windows._SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR = record   // size 20
    Revision: Byte;                              // offset 0
    Sbz1: Byte;                                  // offset 1
    Control: Word;                               // offset 2
    Owner: Pointer;                              // offset 4
    Group: Pointer;                              // offset 8
    Sacl: PACL;                                  // offset 12
    Dacl: PACL;                                  // offset 16
  end;
```

#### Not so easy in C++Builder

But in C++Builder this is not so easy. I currently use a number of macros and simple RTTI (`typeid(x).name()`) like this:

*members.h*

```cpp
#ifndef MEMBERS_H
#define MEMBERS_H

void print_member(const char *type, const char *name, int offset)
{
    char buffer[256];
    sprintf(buffer, "    %s %s;", type, name);
    printf("%-48s // offset %d\n", buffer, offset);
}

#define print(member) \
    print_member(typeid(((type *)0)->member).name(), #member, offsetof(type, member))

#define start \
    printf("struct %-42s/\/ size %d\n{\n", typeid(type).name(), sizeof(type))

#define end \
    printf("};\n\n");

#endif
```

I know that that is ugly and makes C++ purists cringe, but it works. I use it in simple test programs like this:

```cpp
#include "windows.h" // for the struct type I want to inspect
#include "members.h"

int main()
{    
    #define type SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR
    start;
        print(Revision);
        print(Sbz1);
        print(Control);
        print(Owner);
        print(Group);
        print(Sacl);
        print(Dacl);
    end;
    #undef type
}
```

And I get this kind of output:

```cpp
struct _SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR                      // size 20
{
    unsigned char Revision;                      // offset 0
    unsigned char Sbz1;                          // offset 1
    unsigned short Control;                      // offset 2
    void * Owner;                                // offset 4
    void * Group;                                // offset 8
    _ACL * Sacl;                                 // offset 12
    _ACL * Dacl;                                 // offset 16
};
```

### Question

Is there a way to make the C++Builder part more elegant and performant? Ideally, I only provide the type (e.g. `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`) and the code generates the output for all its data members.

Currently, unlike in the Delphi example, I must query each member field explicitly. I do get the output I need, but it is much more work than in Delphi.

I couldn't find a way to make C++Builder generate RTTI similar to the extended RTTI in Delphi. Is there a way, using the more extended capabilities of C++ (or actually C++Builder), e.g. templates and/or the new features of C++11 (or C++14?) to automate this better, i.e. I just supply the name of the struct and the code does the same as Delphi? Does C++Builder provide better RTTI than the very basic little bit of RTTI that normal C++ provides?

#### Note

I am only interested in the data members of simple (Windows 32 or 64 bit) POD API structs, not in classes or structs with (possibly virtual) member functions as used in general C++.

Comment: In a word, no. C++ simply doesn't have the rich RTTI that Delphi does. Not even in C++Builder, which has many extensions to bridge support between Delphi and C++. There is a `__declspec(delphirtti)` extension, but it doesn't work on pure C++ types that dont cross the C++/Delphi boundary.

Comment: @Remy: bummer. And no other way either, I suppose?

Comment: not really, no. What you already have is about as close as you are going to get with pure C++ (other than maybe replacing the ugly macros with nicer template wrappers)

Comment: @Remy: even the nicer template wrappers would be a great help. Could you write a short answer?

Comment: @Remy: I just thought of something: the debugger can do something like this, so the debug info could be of some help. Is there a way to read the debug info or a map file of some sort? The code doesn't have to be in C++, it can be done in Delphi too, as long as I can display it the way I do above, or similar. Even if you don't know, I'll investigate this. I want to automate this a little more than I can do now.

Comment: Instead of using macros, you could look for templates and in particular combine them with type traits and/or "if consexpr". This stuff comes with c++17 and I dont think it will work with c++ Builder, maybe in a future release. But for sure you could use templates and that would be a nice improvement for sure!

Comment: @Alberto: I can imagine that templates would make it better, but **how**? I don't know C++ well enough, especially not the new features, to even know where to start. Type traits?

Comment: Type traits are used with templates and they give you info about the type that is being used (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits). I cannot explain here but that page will give you an idea! Basically, they let you know info about the type (is value, is float...) and they can give compile time errors

Comment: Instead the if constexpr (condition) is good because it can completely DISCARD one of the two branches that is not reached by the if. This is possibile because constexpr gives compile time evaluation. The branch that is not used will be removed by the compiler. This is extremely useful, you should read about it because c++17 brings in a lot!

Comment: @Rudy try to read C++ High Performance and/or C++ 17 by Nico Josuttis. If you already have c++ basics, they will open a new world to you! And they do not cost a lot

Comment: @AlbertoMiola: I don't want to become a C++ expert. But the name Josuttis sounds familiar.